# Recursively ignore directory by name using .tfignore

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfignore

I have the following folder structure:

```
foo1/
  node_modules/
foo2/
  node_modules/
  bar/
    node_modules/
.tfignore
```

A single `.tfignore` file is in the root directory.

What should I add to the `.tfignore` in order to ignore `node_modules` directories recursively no matter where they are in the directory hierarchy?

---

There're a lot of questions similar to mine. But all are pretty wide. I want to keep it simple. Please don't suggest anything with "Pending Changes". I only need a single line in `.tfignore`

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried just adding `node_modules` to your `.tfignore`?  What do your pending changes look like when you do?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I feel awkward, but you're right. Simple `node_modules` did it. I tried \\**\node_modules\, \\*\node_modules\ and it wasn't working.

Comment: @EdwardThomson you could post your answer and I'll accept it. Just in case anybody's as silly as I.

Comment: No need to feel awkward - I couldn't remember how `.tfignore` worked and I shipped that code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`.tfignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts) file will ignore the given pattern in *all* subdirectories (unless otherwise specified).  And it will ignore files *or* folders with the given name.  For folders, it will apply recursively.

As a result, a `.tfignore` with:

```
node_modules
```

will ignore any folder named `node_modules` in your filesystem hierarchy, and it will ignore them recursively.

Comment: What should I write if i only want to ignore the pattern bar/node_modules?